# If I have 2 lists of words how to find if the 2 sentences formed from them are similar based on a 2D similarity matrix given

Tags: python, string, list, multidimensional-array, similarity

I have two lists

```
l1=["humans" ,"are","intelligent"]
l2=["men","are","brilliant"]
```

And a similarity matrix

```
m=[["humans","men"],["intelligent","smart"],["smart","brilliant"]]
```

The above matrix indicates that *("humans" and "men")* are similar words and *("intelligent" and "smart")*
the transitive property also holds true so *(intelligent and brilliant)* are also similar

2 sentences are given

```
"men are brilliant"
"humans are intelligent "
```

Write a code to check if 2 sentences are similar or not

Comment: What have you written

Comment: This is clearly homework.  You have to make an attempt to solve the problem on your own before you ask for our help.

Comment: What do you mean by *write a code to check if 2 sentences are similar or not*

Comment: The problem statement is clear enough.  Two sentences are "similar" if all the corresponding words match in the similarity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

- Since transitive property holds true you need to make different combinations of the combined list where the property holds true.
- For example in your case:  `["intelligent", "smart"],["smart", "brilliant"]` these two lists must be combined.
- So when you combine these two lists you get `["intelligent", "smart", "brilliant"]` Now its different combinations should be found, you can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` for this.
- Before you find the combination you need to know for which list this property holds true, So for this purpose we can make use of `set.isdisjoint` which returns
  `True` if two list contains distinct elements else returns `False`
- Now split the sentence and remove non-keywords words that are not present in the matrix, then zip them and check if it is in the new list that you constructed using above methods

So here is the demonstration of my idea( which you can improve upon):

```py
import itertools
m=[["humans", "men"],["intelligent", "smart"],["smart", "brilliant"]]

a = "men are smart"
b = "humans are intelligent"

new_matrix = set()
for x in range(len(m)):
    for y in range(x+1, len(m)):

        if not set(m[x]).isdisjoint(m[y]):
            new_matrix.add(tuple(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(set(m[x])|set(m[y]), 2))) # or m[x]+m[y]

        else:
            #new_matrix.add(tuple(sorted(set(m[y]))))
            new_matrix.add(tuple(itertools.combinations(m[x], 2)))


new_matrix2 = []
for x in new_matrix:  # removing the nested tuple generated by itertools
    if type(x[0]) == tuple: 
        new_matrix2.extend((sorted(x) for x in set(x)))

    else:
        new_matrix2.append(sorted(x))

new_a = [x for x in a.split() if x in itertools.chain(*m)]  # remove the strings that are not present in the matrix
new_b = [x for x in b.split() if x in itertools.chain(*m)]

print(all(sorted(x) in new_matrix2 for x in itertools.zip_longest(new_a, new_b, fillvalue='')))
```

The above program prints `True` if the sentences are similar.

Another method, I thought about was to use sets union and remove the intersection. But This method doesn't work well if your inner list contains more elements

```py
new_matrix = set()
for x in range(len(m)):
    for y in range(x+1, len(m)):
        
        if not set(m[x]).isdisjoint(m[y]):
            intersection = set(m[x]) & set(m[y])
            union = set(m[x]) | set(m[y])
            union.remove(*intersection)

            new_matrix.add(tuple(sorted(union)))
        
          
        else:

            new_matrix.add(tuple(sorted(m[x])))
            new_matrix.add(tuple(sorted(m[y])))


new_a = [x for x in a.split() if x in itertools.chain(*m)]  # remove the strings that are not present in the matrix
new_b = [x for x in b.split() if x in itertools.chain(*m)]

print(all(tuple(sorted(x)) in new_matrix for x in zip(new_a, new_b)))
```